# Is there an elementary proof that there are infinitely many primes p satisfying the following:

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

$
\begin{align*}
p &\equiv 1\pmod{48}\\
2^{(p-1)/4}&\equiv -1 \pmod{p}, \text{ and}\\
6^{(p-1)/4}&\equiv 1 \pmod{p}.
\end{align*}
$

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Maybe latexify the problem statement?

Comment: It seems that biquadratic reciprocity has to come in somewhere - is there any reason you think that an elementary proof exists?

Comment: The original proof uses the Tchebotarev density theorem. I have hopes that something easier may work. Something that will fit into my classroom notes on graph decomposition.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Questions like this are very welcome, and interesting. One thing that may not be obvious is that many people here don't read the title when reading the question, so the actual question should not depend on anyone reading the title. Also, you can use LaTeX to format your questions and answers, more or less exactly the way you would use it in a paper, with dollar signs to delimit the mathematics.

Comment: It doesn't feel like Chebotarev is necessary - Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progression should already be enough, if you are willing to get your hands dirty to show directly for instance 2 is a QR but not a fourth root mod p iff p satisfies some congruence conditions, which would of course follows from biquadratic reciprocity.

Comment: The conditions are equivalent to 2,3,4 are squares, but not 8-th powers and $p\equiv 1 \pmod{16}$. Does this help?

Comment: Thus is the kind of problem where one *expects* to invoke Tchebotarev's result. It would be interesting to see how to avoid it in this case, if at all possible.